# What does 'Taxonimize' mean here?

Tags: terminology, intelligence

I was reading a news article about increasing IQ and one psychologist wrote

> Many of the changes in IQ are correlated to changes in schooling. One way that school increases IQ is to teach children to "taxonimize," or group things systematically instead of thematically. This kind of thinking is rewarded on many IQ tests.

https://www.livescience.com/36143-iq-change-time.html

What does taxonomise mean here? And does anyone know what specific study they are talking about?

Comment: The answer is in the question: "... *or group things systematically instead of thematically*, no? And what study? There is no reference to a study in your question, just a statement from a person?

Comment: @AliceD I don't have a background in psychology so if those are well known terms I really don't know what that refers to either. I can't find even a definition of anything that seems to relate to this by those names.

Comment: This is not a word specific to psychology.  It is a word in general use but is often used in Biology.  Taxonomise means [*"To assign a taxonomy to a particular species."*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/taxonomize) or in other words based on the quote, **to assign a classification to a particular group of things**